# Setting unique or check constraint to make a field unique in each entry of another unique field

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table as follows :

```
.-----------------------------.
|    mytable                  |
-------------------------------
| id     | primary key        |
| field  | varchar            | 
| name   | varchar            |
-------------------------------
```

`id` and `field` will be unique. But I want to make `name` also unique for each `field`. e.g.

```
id      | field         | name 
------------------------------------------------------
1       | f1            | n1
2       | f1            | n2
3       | f1            | n1      < Should be voilated
4       | f2            | n1      < Should be fine
```

Comment: A unique(field, name) constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index idx_mytable_name_field on mytable(name, field)
```

Note:  this solution will not work if you have `NULL` values in the column and you want the constraint to apply to them as well.  By default Postgres ignores `NULL` values.